# Python : How to order in a set

Tags: python, set

So ive been doing this assignment that returns the integer that doesn't have a matching integer or -(integer). so far I have:

```
def only_once(a):
    c = a
    z = []
    freq = Counter(c)
    for key, value in freq.items():
        if value == 1:
            z.append(key)
    return z
```

The main problem however, is the ordering. if I put in a large list, and then using the function it will just rearrange the list into a set order.
So how do i make the ordering of z be like a but with the removed variables.

Comment: If you look at the docs for collections.Counter, you will see a recipe for an OrderedCounter. Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
def only_once(a):
    c = a
    z = []
    freq = Counter(c)
    for key in a:
        if freq[key] == 1:
            z.append(key)
    return z
```

Or as a list comprehension

```
def only_once(a):
    freq = Counter(a)
    z = [key for key in a if freq[key] == 1]
```

Comment: What is the problem with `for key, value in freq.items():` doesn't it access in order?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, no. That was mentioned in the question